# Pass new variable value to function that is lower in the DOM

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a conditional statement inside of a function that is set to fire another function with specific values each time it's run (in this case the value of var changes each time a different portion of the conditional is run:

```
function runOne() {
    if (s=='false') {
       runTwo();
    } else if (p=='false') {
       runTwo();
    } else if (d=='false') { 
       runTwo();
    }
}

function runTwo() {
 addSomething(k);
}
```

How do I let the second function know what the new value of k is each time? And how would I set this up in general?

Thanks anyone who can help!

Comment: I don't see the variable 'var' anywhere in your code.

Comment: sorry, i meant k instead of var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could pass it as a parameter... like this:

```
function runOne() {
    if (s=='false') {
       runTwo(s);
    } else if (p=='false') {
       runTwo(p);
    } else if (d=='false') { 
       runTwo(d);
    }
}

function runTwo(newVar) {
 addSomething(newVar);
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Figured it would be a param. Apologies for the newb question. There is much more involved than that to what I need to do, but I figured this would be the simplest way of confirming my thought process. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, variables defined on a level somewhere "up" from a function are accessible within that function. Global variables are memebrs of the `window` object and are accessible everywhere in the script, even if they're defined after a function where you use them (due to variable hoisting). See [this](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting) for a better explanation.

```
var foo = 1; // window.foo

function a()
{
    alert(foo);
    alert(bar);
}

var bar = 2; // window.bar

a(); // alerts 1, then 2
```